# Simulate millions of users with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have a system that should be able to handle millions of users requests concurrently. In order to check how the system handles the load, I setup a cluster of JMeter servers (slaves), and one controller (client).

I have a database of all users (~10M), and I need each request sent to be from a different user.

I am wondering how I can implement such a thing in JMeter. Basically, I thought about dividing a range of users (let's say 100,000) per each slave, and then within a given slave, each request should read a new user from the local 100,000 list, and delete it. Thus, I will eventually send a request from every user.

The thing is while this idea sounds logical theoretically, I do not exactly know how to implement it using the JMeter terms. Also, I am not sure how to read from database in the test, although I could theoretically read it in advance into a text file, and have each slave contain the text file with its 100,000 users portion.

I can setup a very large cluster of machines, so scale will not be the issue here. Just how to set it all up.

Comment: why don't you try load testing on cloud ?. Different tools are present for the same.

Comment: Actually, the JMeter cluster runs on Google Compute Engine... :-) Thing is I am not sure how to distribute the users:

1. Between the slaves
2. Within each slave, between the threads.

Additionally, if know other (cloud) tools that you think can do this better, please let me know which..

Comment: blazemeter,tlaloc (my team uses tlaloc)

Comment: At least for blazemeter, more than 1,000,000 concurrent users will cost me >1000$ per month, for enterprise plan. Currently, I am in a prototype phase, so I want to stick to a free solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to provide Jmeter with a list of parameters is to use a CSV file:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config
You can configure the CSV dataset config to do make every thread use a different line in the CSV. Each engine will need to have it’s own unique CSV file, because the sharing mode does nto work between engines in distributed testing (you can try to automate this part, this can be interesting to do :) ).

This is how your script should look like:
1. Thread Group
1.1 HTTP sampler (login)
1.1.1 CSV dataset config
1.2 second http sampler
etc...

The login sampler will use the parameters loaded by from the CSV file, so for every ’login’ it will use a different line.

Distributed testing is pretty simple:
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html
Keep in mind that running 100K concurrent users on a single Jmeter load engine will be hard (Jmeter consumes resources on the server, so you will need lots of CPU and memory). So you should also monitor the engines.
Also 1M users will cause a lot of data that the engines will send back to the console, so you might need to start a bunch of distributed tests in parallel, and at the end aggregate the results.

Cheers,

Comment: I need the configurable data to be json object, since I am sending the JSON in the request body. Is that also possible to implement with CSV data config set?

Comment: Currently there is no config element which can read JSON format. You can use a beanshell script to try and format a JSON file to the parameters. Another option is to use the HTTP sampler 'body data' option to build a JSON request using the parameters in the CSV.

Comment: @Yaniv Donenfeld
You can always change the values of your JSON input from CSV dataset  
`e.g. {
    "name": "${name}",
    "username": "${Uname}",
    "password": "${Pword}"
}`

Answer (score 0):

This is can be implemented by doing the following steps:

- Taking the user credential dump and saving it to a csv file
- split the csv file. copy 1 file to each Jmeter slave, in the same location on all the 
  machines e.g. "C:\Loadtest\"
- from the controller, give the path of your csv file in "CSV Data Set Config".
- Run the Test.

By doing the above steps, Jmeter controller will start execution of the test by pointing all the Jmeter Slave nodes to use the CSV file in the same location "C:\Loadtest\".
But the trick here is that all the machine will be using different set of users.

Hope this will help.

Comment: One thing I want to make sure about your suggestion: In a single machine, given file such as: C:\LoadTest\usersXX.csv - will all the threads running in parallel read it simultaneously? I need that each user will be sent a request only once, so it's kind of a queue of users that needs to be consumed and emptied - will this how it work? Or will all the threads read the same data?

Comment: Each machine will be accessing the file locally. Even though the name of the file is same on all the machines, the data can be made different. So each slave node will have its own set of data.

  to make sure that 1 user strictly sends only 1 request, make sure the number of threads/users is less than or equal to the number of users in data.

e.g. if want to run a load of 1000 concurrent users on 10 slave nodes. User/threads in controller should be 100.

Comment: Actually, I just saw this post: http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/40707-how-to-setup-a-different-csv-file-for-each-jmeter that explains how to distribute the files between workers with different file name per node.

Comment: It will work in the same manner, only change here is you will be able to give different file name to each data file. The test will not use the CSV data file kept in controller machine. you have to keep file in each Jmeter slave machine in the same path as defined in controller.